# `object.__setattr__(self, ..., ...)` instead of `setattr(self, ..., ...)`?

Tags: python, class, methods

Following is the `__init__` method of the `Local` class from the `werkzeug` library:

```
def __init__(self):
    object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})
    object.__setattr__(self, '__ident_func__', get_ident)
```

I don't understand two things about this code:

1. Why did they write

   ```
   object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})
   ```

   instead of simply

   ```
   `setattr(self, '__storage__', {})`
   ```
2. Why did they even use `__setattr__` if the could simply write

   ```
   self.__storage__ = {}
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ensures that the default Python definition of `__setattr__` is used. It's generally used if the class has overridden `__setattr__` to perform non-standard behaviour, but you still wish to access the original `__setattr__` behaviour.

In the case of werkzeug, if you look at the `Local` class you'll see `__setattr__` is defined like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    ident = self.__ident_func__()
    storage = self.__storage__
    try:
        storage[ident][name] = value
    except KeyError:
        storage[ident] = {name: value}
```

Instead of setting attributes in the dictionary of the object, it sets them in the `__storage__` dictionary that was initialized previously. In order to set the `__storage__` attribute at all (so that it may be accessed like `self.__storage__` later), the original definition of `__setattr__` from object must be used, which is why the awkward notation is used in the constructor.

Comment: I'll just add that although it looks awkward in the source, it provides a nice interface for users of the class.

Answer (score 3):

They want to explicitly use the base `object.__setattr__` implementation instead of a possibly overridden method instance method somewhere else in the inheritance chain. `Local` implements its own `__setattr__` so this avoids that.

Answer (score 2):

Because the same class defines `__setattr__` and this needs to bypass that, since the first line says `self.__ident_func__()` which wouldn't work yet.