# Why is object.__setattr__.__get__(self, Attribute) used for Attribute's __init__ in attrs/_make.py

Tags: python, python-descriptors, python-attrs

I enjoy working with `attr` and decided to read some of the source code. One part that caught my eye was the following ([source](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/77914a4b2748de9931236f46f22bdf03c5e58b21/src/attr/_make.py#L2034)):

```
# Cache this descriptor here to speed things up later.
bound_setattr = _obj_setattr.__get__(self, Attribute)

# Despite the big red warning, people *do* instantiate `Attribute`
# themselves.
bound_setattr("name", name)
bound_setattr("default", default)
bound_setattr("validator", validator)
```

where `_obj_setattr` is defined as `object.__setattr__`.

I am curious as to why this is done. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041518/object-setattr-self-instead-of-setattrself) stackoverflow response and found it very useful, but it does not cover the part about `__get__`. I have read a bit about `descriptors` but have not fully wrapped my head around them. So, my question is, why use `_obj_setattr.__get__(self, A)("name", name)`, as opposed to `object.__setattr__(self, "name", name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `__get__` method of a function returns a bound method object. Normally you do this by doing a lookup directly on an instance, like `self.__setattr__`. But this code expects to be used in situations where the `__setattr__` method may be overridden in a subclass, so doing a direct lookup of `object.__setattr__` and binding it to `self` is preferred.

While you could do `object.__setattr__(self, "name", name)` and so on, each time you use it, that would be a little bit slower (since attribute lookup is not very fast and we'd need it for `object.__setattr__`), and not very convenient because we always need to pass `self` manually. Binding the method to `self` gives us slightly better performance and it is a more convenient thing to type, so it's a win-win.